# Accessing private files on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization, digital-signature, privacy

I have a private s3 bucket. I am trying to access it with the authorization. I am managing to do that only by generated a pre-signed url for each object in the bucket using AWS-SDK, which is not practical at all.
Also I have tried configuring the bucket policy and give premission only to a specific range of ips, but it won't work. How can I see what's wrong there?
What do you think is the best approach for accessing a private bucket? I am a bit confused.

```
policy:
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [

        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "public/private IP of ec2 instance/32"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "myIPAddress/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: *"Also I have tried configuring the bucket policy and give premission only to a specific range of ips, but it won't work."*  Well, doing that **does** work.  It might be helpful if you showed us the policy you are trying to use to allow access by IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default accounts are restricted from accessing S3 unless they have been given access via policy. However, S3 is designed by default to allow any IP address access. So to block IP's you would have to specify denies explicitly in the policy instead of allows.

You Should flip around the policy from allowing access from only my IP address to denying access from everywhere that is NOT my IP address.

So I Think You Might be Using this :

```
{
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPAllow",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::: bucketname",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "CIDR Of Allowed IP"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You Should Try This :

```
{
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPDeny",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::: bucket name*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "CIDR Of Allowed IP"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I Hope This Helps

Comment: I dont know how you managed to find out whats wrong without even knowing what I ve done! Thank you!

Comment: I am now trying to give access to 3 different IPs using the same statement 3 times. But this seems to not allow access for any resource.

Comment: Can you Please Show the Code

Comment: I think , You Need To Add every IP in same Place:
Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "ip1"
                      "aws:SourceIp": "ip2"
                }
You Can Try This but I am Not Sure.

Comment: the moment I am saving it it is deleting the rest and keeps the first ip in the list only. I ll do further research for the syntax! thank you!

Comment: Tried Comma Separated Values ?

Comment: It is supposed to be like this:  "aws:SourceIp":  [
                        "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx",
                        "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx"
                    ]

Comment: Yes Comma Separated Values.